# I need to execute a varchar SQLcode in my Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, database

I have a Stored Procedure that saves the code in a varchar variable and i need execute this code.

Procedure:

```
 delimiter $$
 create procedure eixos_caminhao (in numeroEixos int)
 begin
     set @comando := 'select classe, velocidade, date(data) as data, 
 pesoEixo1, pesoEixo2';
     if (numeroEixos > 2) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo3');
     if (numeroEixos > 3) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo4');
     if (numeroEixos > 4) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo5');
     if (numeroEixos > 5) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo6');
     if (numeroEixos > 6) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo7');
     if (numeroEixos > 7) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo8');
     if (numeroEixos > 8) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo9');
     set @comando:= concat(@comando, ' from tb_vbv');
 end;
 delimiter;
```

Now, how can i execute this Sql in my varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `EXECUTE(@var)` function for this.

```
EXECUTE(@command);
```

Comment: Thanks!! i dont have reputation for vote this awnser, but works!

Comment: You can mark this as a good answer under the upvote with your reputation.